# How can I browse an external hard drive in a remote Ubuntu machine via SSH?

Tags: mount, ssh

I'm on my computer at home (Win10). I'd like to access an external drive plugged into another computer running Ubuntu (I use the Ubuntu computer exclusively for a Plex media server, and have a mounted external hard drive that contains all my media).

I can use PuTTY to SSH to the Ubuntu computer, but can't figure out how to "move" from the Ubuntu disk that SSH drops me into, to the mounted external drive.

My end goal is to mass-delete all *.jpg and *.png files in the Music folder of my external media drive. I've figured out how to find and delete those files, but I can't figure out how to "move" to the external drive in SSH to run those commands.

Comment: `cd path/to/mountpoint` . . . ?

Comment: @steeldriver and Lsblk to find your drive

Comment: I would use the commands `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` and `df` to identify the available partitions, and then use the command suggested by @steeldriver, `cd path/to/mountpoint` , to change the working directory to the external hard disk drive. (I assume that the partition(s) on the external drive is/are already mounted. Please tell us if you need help to mount it/them.)